how to parse csv using from_csv with schema_of_csv?
I want to parse csv data which is the value of column in another table. The thing is that I don't know the schema of this csv data.
Currently, I am trying the query like this: SELECT from_csv(csv_col, schema_of_csv(csv_col)) AS csv_data FROM csv_data_table; but it looks like schema_of_csv does not accept column names.
Could you please provide me with an example of a query that I can use? Thanks

are you using Azure databricks?

nope, directly in databricks account
